# UISegmented Control with same tableview and a uibutton in cells

Tags: ios, tableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I am using a segmented control to display expired and available tickets in same tableview whose cells have a UIButton to open maps of a particular location
Now the problem is when i switch between tickets tags of uibutton gets messed up.
Is there anyway to reset the tag each time tableview reloads?

Comment: How do you set the tags currently?

Comment: if let button = cell.viewwithtag(7) as? uibutton {
button.tag = indexpath.row

}

Comment: Where are you doing this? You need to share your code to provide context. Edit the question with your code.